# Stored procedure in SQL Server that returns total count of columns in table and distinct count of values in each column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I need a stored procedure that takes any table name as a parameter and returns total count of rows and distinct count of values in each column of that particular table when executed.

Let's take the sample table as below:

```
create table journey
(
    Src varchar(255),  
    Dest varchar(255)
)

insert into journey 
values ('Jaipur', 'Mumbai'), ('Mumbai', 'Jaipur'), ('Kolkata', 'Bangalore'), 
       ('Bangalore', 'Indore'),('Indore', 'Lucknow'), ('Lucknow', 'Indore')
```

Can anybody help me with this task of dynamic SQL.

I have made an attempt which is not giving the result but runs successfully when specific table name is fixed. Can anybody suggest where the code is lagging?

```
create procedure test @table_name varchar(255)
AS

BEGIN 

SELECT count(*) as [Number of columns]
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = '@table_name'



 SELECT @table_name = 
     Replace( 
       'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' +'COUNT(DISTINCT(' + column_name + ')) As ' 
       + column_name + ' ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
       FROM information_schema.columns 
       WHERE table_name = '@table_name' 
       for xml path('')),2,200000) + 'FROM @table_name','&#x0D;','')
 exec(@table_name)

END

exec test @table_name = "journey";
```

Comment: How can it be that it "runs successfully" but "is not giving the result"?

Comment: @mustaccio Because of `WHERE table_name = '@table_name'` (instead of `WHERE table_name = @table_name`), the outcome is NULL, and `EXEC (@variable_that_is_null);` runs just fine - no results, but no error message.

Comment: Well I guess I have a different definition of success then. For me it would be when the procedure returns expected results.

Comment: @mustaccio Well, the output is `The command(s) completed successfully.` So it may not have been the OP's definition of success, but literally paraphrasing the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple concatenation like this doesn't need `FOR XML PATH`, please use `sys.columns` and `sp_executesql`, and I think you've over-used `table_name` and `@table_name` a little bit.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test   -- always use schema prefix
  @table_name nvarchar(255) -- object names need to be nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF OBJECT_ID(@table_name) IS NOT NULL -- protect yourself from SQL injection
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT TotalCount = COUNT(*)';

    SELECT @sql += N',' + QUOTENAME('DISTINCT ' + name) 
                 + N' = COUNT(DISTINCT ' + QUOTENAME(name) + N')'
      FROM sys.columns 
      WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
      -- AND max_length <> -1; -- you may need this on some versions to omit MAX types

    SET @sql += N' FROM ' + @table_name + N';';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
  END
END
GO
```

Further reading:

- [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)
- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using EXEC() instead of sp_executesql](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql)